# Can I use 32-bit Python to write a debugger for 64-bit processes?

Tags: python, windows, 32bit-64bit

I'm following along in the book Gray Hat Python by Justin Seitz, I've come across other questions and answers on this website explaining that the code in this book was meant for 32-bit processes, so the example as is will not work on the calculator.exe process in my 64-bit Windows 10.

Is there any way I can modify the code in the future, or write my debugger from scratch in the future using 32-bit Python interpreter that can interface with a 64-bit process? Or will I need to install and use 64-bit Python with 64-bit libraries to debug, attach to, and work with 64-bit processes in Windows 10?

Comment: Writing your own is always an option.

Comment: I downloaded Python 2.7.12 64-bit interpreter and installed it alongside my 32-bit version without any complications. I ran the code I had written from following along in the book as-is and was able to attach to a 64-bit process with no complications.

My Question still stands though, is it possible to attach to a 64-bit process using a 32-bit interpreter?

Also I was surprised all the libraries I i'm currently using installed just fine in the 64-bit version of Python, I don't understand how it all works but I thought I would need to find separate 64-bit versions.

Comment: Most of your Python libraries will be 90% python, which is basically plain text. You only start getting into potential issues if your library uses binary extensions.